# How do I add labels to individual bars on a bar chart using Dojo charting

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

Can the bars on a Dojo chart be labelled with the value? I have the tooltips but I would like the bar values to be shown all the time and for when the graph is printed.

Also I have some bar charts which can run over several pages. When you print the charts, it will just cut off when it reaches the end of the page.

Is it possible to print the x axis at the bottom of the page for each page break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the bars on a Dojo chart be labelled with the value?

Not yet. See http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/11366

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply, do you know if there is a way to page the graphs when printed?